# How to properly write the import statement

Tags: python

How do I properly write something like this:

```
from ../lib.model import mymodel
```

Here is the tree:

```
lib----->model---->mynodel.py
 |
 |----->myscript--->myscript.py
```

Comment: If you are making a library you might consider using [relative imports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Comment: He does in my opinion. But the relative imports are in a sister/brother directory (but still relative). It's not `/lib`, it's a `lib`

Comment: Where is the script with the `import` statement?

Answer (score 1):

If `lib` is a package, run `myscript` as a module and import `mymodel` like this:

```
from ..model import mymodel    # relative import
```

Or:

```
from lib.model import mymodel    # absolute import
```

To run `myscript.py` as a module in the `lib` package, do one of the following:

- run a program in the folder containing `lib` that imports `lib.myscript.myscript`
- run `myscript.py` as a module from the folder containing `lib`, using `python -m lib.myscript.myscript`

Comment: Doesn't this result in quite complex behavior? A programmer should set the proper current directory before executing the program? It solves the problem, but is quite complicated in my opinion.

Comment: @CommuSoft Normally, the `.py` files inside a package are modules, so they would only be imported and not executed directly. This eliminates the problem you're describing.

Comment: Moreover it doesn't work. Using python 2.7 on WinXP SP3 I am getting: future feature absolute_imports is not defined.

Comment: My bad, it's `absolute_import` without an s.

Comment: @flornquake: yeah, but it's more a separation of responsibilities. A script has the responsibility to import the proper modules, not a programmer calling the script or some python program on top of the two...

Comment: @Igor just realized `absolute_import` isn't needed.

Comment: @CommuSoft The only responibility that the programmer has is to treat `lib` as a package and `myscript` as a module if that's what they are. If you do that, the imports within the package will always work out.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Generally, modules are installed to a directory in `$PYTHONPATH`, and scripts just use absolute imports.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I gave a +1. There is nothing wrong with your answer. But personally I think the method introduces useless extra responsibilities. Although I have to admit that I don't know Pythons house rules :D. The only argument I can imagine is that `$PYTHONPATH` can be system protected, so you cant install new modules.

Answer (score 1):

if your script is using `lib` you can create a `setup.py` using file for your project using `setuptools`

Using setuptools `develop` command will create a "development mode" version of your project and put it on your python path.  It then becomes easy to use it like you would use any python package.

your setup.py can be as simple as:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name = "lib",
    version = "0.1dev",
    packages = find_packages(),
)
```

Then you can develop on your project like

`python setup.py develop`

Now you can import your package into any script you want

`from lib.model import model`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you call from `myscript.py`.

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../model/')
import mynodel
```

`mynodel` is probably `mymodel`, I think you made a typo in your post.

Never put the extension at the imprt statement.

`sys.path` is a list of paths where python will look for library files. You can simply add a relative path to the directory you want. By putting it at the front of the list, you ensure that python will first look for the file at the specified path (say for instance there is a library with the same name, your file will have priority).

Furthermore it could be useful to give the output of `tree` (a linux and `cmd` (Windows) command). This gives standardized output.